# How to renew Google Access Token with Google Refresh Token

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I am using the `GoogleAuthProvider` from Firebase to log users in my app. I want to access the user's calendar to display upcoming events. For this I use the Google Calendar API with the Access token I receive from the login. However the token only lasts for an hour. I also get a refresh token, which I assume is to renew the access token, but I can't find any documentation on how to use it. I use VueJS v2 for the frontend and firebase for the backend.

Comment: You need to work out on communication. Don't think anyone will respond. You tag everything but no `Google-Calendar-Api` https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that refresh token is a tool that generates the temporal access token. If your scenario uses an access token beyond its lifetime, you would need to get a new access token by using the refresh token. Please read this article to learn more about [refreshing tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#5.-refresh-the-access-token,-if-necessary.) in different setups. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline) you can see an example of token refreshing in a web server scenario.

Comment: The second link is what I needed. I don't have any specific backend server and I need to pass the client ID and client Secret which must not be given to the client, does that mean that I need to use a Firebase function as backend (the Client ID and Client Secret would be stored in it) ?

Comment: @MVTKVM You need to store the client's secret in a private place. It could be in your Firebase app or in any other private server.